# Single dialog for "open file" and "create new document"

Tags: qt, openfiledialog

Is it possible to use some form of `QFileDialog` to get a native (MacOS) dialog like the one below, where besides selecting a file, the user can choose to create a new document? I believe I have read all available documentation on the topic, but I could not find an answer.

(Note: This is the initial pick-a-file-or-create-a-new-one from Keynote. I am trying to replicate this behaviour).

[image]

**EDIT** As requested, I include some code.  THis is standard pyqt5 boilerplate.

```
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

filedialog = QFileDialog(None)
filedialog.setDefaultSuffix("texd")
filedialog.setNameFilter("TeX Document Bundle (*.texd);; TeX Template Bundle (*.textemplate)")
filedialog.setOption(QFileDialog.ReadOnly)
selected = filedialog.exec()
if selected:
    filename = filedialog.selectedFiles()[0]
    print(filename)
    print(selected)
return
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. See this link for example: https://forum.qt.io/topic/47089/may-i-have-a-create-new-file-dialog-analogous-to-qfiledialog-getsavefilename/4
If you found yourself unable to create such a dialog, you should post enough code for us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MysteriousUser Your example code is the standard "save as" dialog, which is not what I am asking. I edited the answer to include some (boilerplate) code.